# How to change the order of the group in the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Name   WT  Mutant
'cellular process'  200 2
'Biological phase'  150 5
'cell process'  100 9", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

Using the above code i am unable to change the group position in the graph.[image]

I need WT group first and Mutant group second. Thanks for your help in advance.

I need to change the position of the group as above stated. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set levels in `name`

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c("WT", "Mutant"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]